# Writing text on an image with HTML

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm new to HTML and want to display image shown on left.

I have displayed the image which is a `table row` but I'm not able to get that text (**IN** shown below *blog.com*).

How can I write on the image?

Any help appreciated.

[image]

---

### EDIT

I tried

```
.logoBg
{
    background-image: url('images/logo01.gif');
    background-color: #72c2dd;
}
```

and

```
<tr class="logoBg">
    <td colspan=5>IN
    </td>
    </tr>
```

But I'm only getting text and background color, but **NO** background image.

Comment: use something like `<p>` to contain your text give it an absolute position and move it about, you may need to wrap the `<img>` and `<p>` in a relatively positioned `<div>`. [here](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) is some more info. or use background ^^

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As an example:

You could use this as your HTML:

```
<tr>
<div class="image">
  <img alt="" src="http://www.YourDomain.com/img/yourImage.jpg" />
  <div class="text">
    <p>This is some demonstration text</p>
    <p>This is some more wonderful text</p>
  </div>
</div>
</tr>
```

then this as your CSS:

```
.image {
    position:relative;
}
.image .text {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    width:300px;
}
```

This will place text directly on an image.

Answer (score 2):

Use the image as a background-image and put the text in the same element:

HTML:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td id="myTableCell">
   In
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.myTableCell {
  background-image: url(Images/MyImage.png);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ecnalyr is right, but if you use `position:absolute`, the position is calculated from the top left corner of your browser. I really doubt that's what you want. Rather, use `position:relative` and position your text using +ve and -ve numbers to position your text on the image relative to wherever you place the div

Answer (score 0):

You can use [background-image](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) css to make the image as a background of this table cell, and write text in that cell.

Answer (score 0):

If the containing element of the image has position: relative applied, then you can add an additional element that is positioned absolutely on top of the image