# How to put a text heading

Tags: html, css

how can i put a header (h1) inside the header image? like this
or how can i put the "Hello World" inside that image header :D

https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/t1.0-9/10489763_237437073119972_1157564384151378847_n.jpg

Comment: this thread has the answer you want![link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339006/writing-text-on-an-image-with-html)

Comment: Set the image as a background image on a div or header element which contains the H1.

Comment: i do that, but i get the image become zoom in

h1 {
 background-image: url("2.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

Comment: Zoom in? ... What does that even mean? It's not a camera lens. Make sure your image is appropriately sized for your container, and specify the container's width and height.

Comment: My comment said to add the image as a background image on a div or header element which contains the H1. That's not what you've tried at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<h1>{ Hello World }</h1>
```

**CSS**

```
h1 { 
    display:inline-block; 
    width:400px; 
    height:150px; 
    text-align:center; 
    background:url("http://placehold.it/400x200") 0 0 no-repeat;
    padding-top:50px;
    margin:0;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CNvvJ/)**